# Facing Performance issue while reading files from GCS using apache beam

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, apache-beam-io

I was trying to read data using wildcard from gcs path. My files is in bzip2 format and there were around 300k files resides in the gcs path with same wildcard expression. I'm using the below code snippet to read files.

```
    PCollection<String> val = p
            .apply(FileIO.match()
                    .filepattern("gcsPath"))
            .apply(FileIO.readMatches().withCompression(Compression.BZIP2))
            .apply(MapElements.into(TypeDescriptor.of(String.class)).via((ReadableFile f) -> {
                try {
                    return f.readFullyAsUTF8String();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    return null;
                }
            }));
```

But the performance is very bad and it will take around 3 days to read that file using above code with the current speed. Is there any alternative api I can use in cloud dataflow to read this amount of files from gcs with ofcourse good performance. I used TextIO earlier, but it was getting failed because of template serialisation limit which is 20MB.

Comment: What's the total transfer size of 300k files?

Comment: Is it running on Dataflow or on your computer?

Comment: @ParthMehta Total transfer size is around 1 TB.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere its running on Dataflow 2.17.0

Comment: The release version are strange... The latest on MVN repository in the 2.19, the latest on github is the 2.16-RC1. Can you have a try on this? So, do you see the same issue with you launch the pipeline in direct runner on your computer? Last questions, what is the machine type that you use in your pipeline? What is the scalability?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere, the "latest release" tag on the github repo seems to be outdated, but the releases are present. Right above 2.16 in small letters I see "... show 7 newer tags", and that shows all the way up to 2.19, just like Maven.

Comment: The stable version 2.18.0 released 2 week earlier. 2.19.0 snapshot is available which is for beta users.

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Could you please upvote this question, so that someone will try to answer this query.

Comment: done.You didn't answer about the machine type and the pipeline scaling. Do you have inputs on this?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere Worker machine-type is n1-standard-16 and I'm using default auto-scaling algorithm. no max-worker set.

Comment: Definitively not an issue of bandwidth or processing capability...

Comment: I don't know why, but FileIO performance is very bad, might be some internal api glitches.

Comment: Do you see Dataflow scaling up at all or is reading handled by one or few workers ? If job is not scaling up this could be due to sizes of compressed files being unbalanced. Dataflow cannot split compressed files so each file will be processed by one worker. Regarding template serialization limit, I think this can be avoided by using the dataflowJobFile option: https://cloud.google.com/dataflow/docs/guides/common-errors

Comment: After fixing the template size error as per chamikara comment, if you use TextIO you can also make use of https://beam.apache.org/releases/javadoc/2.19.0/org/apache/beam/sdk/io/TextIO.Read.html#withHintMatchesManyFiles--

Comment: Did you try to follow @chamikara solution, and then exchange reading method to TextIO?

Comment: @chamikara I already followed all this steps to minimize the tempate serialization size.  But Thanks for your information.

Comment: @RezaRokni I just saw your answer, but I got the same solution yesterday. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below TextIO() code solved the issue.

```
PCollection<String> input = p.apply("Read file from GCS",TextIO.read().from(options.getInputFile())
                        .withCompression(Compression.AUTO).withHintMatchesManyFiles()
                        );
```

withHintMatchesManyFiles() solved the issue. But still I don't know while FileIO performance is so bad.

Comment: I'm not following the solution.  In your original post, I see you reading the whole file as an element into the PCollection while in the second solution, I am seeing your read each line as a separate element (String) into the PCollection.